# roswtf errors after following Install and Configuration of ROS Tutorial

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm new to ROS so I'm following the beginner tutorials. After following the install and configuration steps for my system (ubuntu 13.04), I get the following message from roswtf;

==============================================================

Static checks summary:

Found 2 warning(s).
Warnings are things that may be just fine, but are sometimes at fault

WARNING You are missing core ROS Python modules: rosrelease --
WARNING You are missing Debian packages for core ROS Python modules: rosrelease (python-rosrelease) --

Found 2 error(s).

ERROR Not all paths in ROS_PACKAGE_PATH [/home/gaynier/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/hydro/share:/opt/ros/hydro/stacks] point to an existing directory:

- /opt/ros/hydro/stacks

ERROR Not all paths in PYTHONPATH [/home/gaynier/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages] point to a directory:

- /home/gaynier/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

==========================================================================

Sooooo, wtf?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/96496/roswtf-errors-after-following-install-and-configuration-of-ros-tutorial/) by [NaiveUser](https://answers.ros.org/users/8326/naiveuser/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-10-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the first error as well, and I found that it is fixed if you go to /opt/ros/hydro/stacks and then do

```
mkdir stacks
```

then you will no longer have the error pop-up. I am relatively new to ROS so I don't know what the folder was for or what this quickfix will do in the long run, but it fixes it for now.

I assume the second error could be fixed via a similar method, but i'd make sure all of your python stuff is up to date on your system before that.

---

Originally posted by [Vvaldir](https://answers.ros.org/users/8431/vvaldir/) with karma: 26 on 2013-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1